# Transactional Synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate

I am new to spring. I have a piece of code written above several of my methods in my project.

```
   @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

What i have been able to search on it is, this code refers to Transactional synchronization and this particular code means that , if two threads come at the same time and make some database update, all the database updations will be executed when both the threads finish their execution. 
I am right on my analysis? Also could anyone throw some more light on this topic.

Comment: No you are wrong... Each thread has its own transaction and when it finishes it will commit. Regardless of the other transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your statement is not right.

If you scrap the word `Synchronization` and you replace the word `thread` with `transaction` from your text then you are on the right path.

`Spring Transaction Management` is not a light matter as it may deceptively appear by the declarative annotations.

Read the detailed [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

Comment: Hi @Dimitrisli, could you look into  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961446/multithreading-issues-for-database-insertion", as it'sthe main issue i asked my question for

Answer (score 0):

No, this is incorrect.

The database updation will be done as soon as a thread transaction finishes.it will not wait for all other threads

Comment: hi Amandeep, can youlook into 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961446/multithreading-issues-for-database-insertion ", this is my main concern.