# Multithreading issues for database insertion

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have a piece of JAVA code that is accessed by multiple threads.

```
synchronized (this.getClass()) 
{
    System.out.println("stsrt");
    certRequest.setRequestNbr(
        generateRequestNumber(
            certInsuranceRequestAddRq.getAccountInfo().getAccountNumberId()));
    System.out.println("outside funcvtion"+certRequest.getRequestNbr());
    reqId = Utils.getUniqueId();
    certRequest.setRequestId(reqId);
    System.out.println(reqId);
    ItemIdInfo itemIdInfo = new ItemIdInfo();
    itemIdInfo.setInsurerId(certRequest.getRequestId());
    certRequest.setItemIdInfo(itemIdInfo);
    dao.insert(certRequest);
    addAccountRel();
    System.out.println("end");
}
```

the function `generateRequestNumber()` generates a request number based on the data fetched from two database tables.

```
public String generateRequestNumber(String accNumber) throws Exception 
{
    String requestNumber = null;
    if (accNumber != null) 
    {
        String SQL_QUERY = "select CERTREQUEST.requestNbr from CertRequest as CERTREQUEST, "
                + "CertActObjRel  as certActObjRel where  certActObjRel.certificateObjkeyId=CERTREQUEST.requestId "
                + " and certActObjRel.certObjTypeCd=:certObjTypeCd "
                + " and certActObjRel.certAccountId=:accNumber ";

        String[] parameterNames = { "certObjTypeCd", "accNumber" };
        Object[] parameterVaues = new Object[] 
        {
            Constants.REQUEST_RELATION_CODE, accNumber 
        };
        List<?> resultSet = dao.executeNamedQuery(SQL_QUERY,
                parameterNames, parameterVaues);

        // List<?> resultSet = dao.retrieveTableData(SQL_QUERY);
        if (resultSet != null && resultSet.size() > 0) {
            requestNumber = (String) resultSet.get(0);
        }
        int maxRequestNumber = -1;
        if (requestNumber != null && requestNumber.length() > 0) {
            maxRequestNumber = maxValue(resultSet.toArray());
            requestNumber = Integer.toString(maxRequestNumber + 1);
        } else {
            requestNumber = Integer.toString(1);
        }
        System.out.println("inside function request number"+requestNumber);
        return requestNumber;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The tables `CertRequest` and `CertActObjRel` used in `generateRequestNumber()` are updated by the functions `"dao.insert(certRequest);"` and `"addAccountRel();"` used in my initial code respectively. Also the `System.out.println()` statements used in my initial code have following output.

```
stsrt
inside function request number73
outside funcvtion73
A1664886-5F84-45A9-AB5F-C69768B83EAD
end
stsrt
inside function request number73
outside funcvtion73
44DAD872-6A1D-4524-8A32-15741FAC0CA9
end
```

If you notice both the threads run in a synchronized manner, but when the request number is generated , it's the same. My assumption is the database updation for `CertRequest` and `CertActObjRel` is done when both the threads finish their execution.

Could anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Is request number a primitive data type like int, string, long. If yes, then they are not thread-safe.

Comment: Seems like everything you have in `generateRequestNumber` could be moved into a database `TRIGGER` instead. This way, you wouldn't need external synchronization (which can create a performance bottleneck).

Comment: the requestNumber is of string type. But even after it is not thread safe, as the value is generated based on database values, primitive data type should not be my concern.

Comment: @Mick, could you throw some more light on a proper fix.